# Spring boot application failing to start with The port may already be in use error

Tags: spring-boot

Spring boot application fails to start with below error. Tried with multiple ports but same issue

```
`org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.ConnectorStartFailedException: Connector configured to listen on port 9330 failed to start
at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.checkConnectorHasStarted(TomcatWebServer.java:232) ~[spring-boot-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.checkThatConnectorsHaveStarted(TomcatWebServer.java:224) ~[spring-boot-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.start(TomcatWebServer.java:202) ~[spring-boot-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.startWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:311) ~[spring-boot-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.finishRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:164) ~[spring-boot-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:552) ~[spring-context-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:142) ~[spring-boot-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775) [spring-boot-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) [spring-boot-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316) [spring-boot-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260) [spring-boot-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248) [spring-boot-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
at com.itm.test.xyz.report.XYZReportApiApplication.main(XYZReportApiApplication.java:15) [classes/:?]`
```

Comment: Which other ports did you try?

Comment: tried 9024, 9122 etc

Comment: Can you please add the full stacktrace?

Comment: Were you ale to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

The message is self-explanatory in this case.

You're trying to start tomcat that has to bind to the port 9330 but this port is already in use by some other process

You can try:

```
netstat -tulpn
```

to see the open ports

I've created a sample spring boot app (from start.spring.io) and started it twice.
The second run (that obviously tries to bind to the same port) produces the following exception:

```
C:\devl\tools\jdk-12.0.1\bin\java.exe "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.2.4\lib\idea_rt.jar=57992:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.2.4\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Users\m00500676\Downloads\demo (2)\demo\target\classes;C:\Users\m00500676\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-web\2.1.4.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-web-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\m00500676\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter\2.1.4.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\m00500676\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot\2.1.4.RELEASE\spring-boot-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\m00500676\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-autoconfigure\2.1.4.RELEASE\spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\m00500676\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-logging\2.1.4.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-logging-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\m00500676\.m2\repository\ch\qos\logback\logback-classic\1.2.3\logback-classic-1.2.3.jar;C:\Users\m00500676\.m2\repository\ch\qos\logback\logback-core\1.2.3\logback-core-1.2.3.jar;C:\Users\m00500676\.m2\repository\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-to-slf4j\2.11.2\log4j-to-slf4j-2.11.2.jar;C:\Users\m00500676\.m2\repository\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-api\2.11.2\log4j-api-2.11.2.jar;C:\Users\m00500676\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\jul-to-slf4j\1.7.26\jul-to-slf4j-1.7.26.jar;C:\Users\m00500676\.m2\repository\javax\annotation\javax.annotation-api\1.3.2\javax.annotation-api-1.3.2.jar;C:\Users\m00500676\.m2\repository\org\yaml\snakeyaml\1.23\snakeyaml-1.23.jar;C:\Users\m00500676\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-json\2.1.4.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-json-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\m00500676\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-databind\2.9.8\jackson-databind-2.9.8.jar;C:\Users\m00500676\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-annotations\2.9.0\jackson-annotations-2.9.0.jar;C:\Users\m00500676\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-core\2.9.8\jackson-core-2.9.8.jar;C:\Users\m00500676\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\datatype\jackson-datatype-jdk8\2.9.8\jackson-datatype-jdk8-2.9.8.jar;C:\Users\m00500676\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\datatype\jackson-datatype-jsr310\2.9.8\jackson-datatype-jsr310-2.9.8.jar;C:\Users\m00500676\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\module\jackson-module-parameter-names\2.9.8\jackson-module-parameter-names-2.9.8.jar;C:\Users\m00500676\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-tomcat\2.1.4.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-tomcat-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\m00500676\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-core\9.0.17\tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar;C:\Users\m00500676\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-el\9.0.17\tomcat-embed-el-9.0.17.jar;C:\Users\m00500676\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-websocket\9.0.17\tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.17.jar;C:\Users\m00500676\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\validator\hibernate-validator\6.0.16.Final\hibernate-validator-6.0.16.Final.jar;C:\Users\m00500676\.m2\repository\javax\validation\validation-api\2.0.1.Final\validation-api-2.0.1.Final.jar;C:\Users\m00500676\.m2\repository\org\jboss\logging\jboss-logging\3.3.2.Final\jboss-logging-3.3.2.Final.jar;C:\Users\m00500676\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\classmate\1.4.0\classmate-1.4.0.jar;C:\Users\m00500676\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-web\5.1.6.RELEASE\spring-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\m00500676\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-beans\5.1.6.RELEASE\spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\m00500676\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-webmvc\5.1.6.RELEASE\spring-webmvc-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\m00500676\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-aop\5.1.6.RELEASE\spring-aop-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\m00500676\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-context\5.1.6.RELEASE\spring-context-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\m00500676\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-expression\5.1.6.RELEASE\spring-expression-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\m00500676\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\slf4j-api\1.7.26\slf4j-api-1.7.26.jar;C:\Users\m00500676\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-core\5.1.6.RELEASE\spring-core-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\m00500676\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-jcl\5.1.6.RELEASE\spring-jcl-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar" com.example.demo.DemoApplication

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.1.4.RELEASE)

2020-02-12 12:47:59.149  INFO 41316 --- [           main] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : Starting DemoApplication on MarkBK-X1 with PID 41316 (started by m00500676 in C:\Users\m00500676\Downloads\demo (2)\demo)
2020-02-12 12:47:59.154  INFO 41316 --- [           main] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2020-02-12 12:48:11.706  INFO 41316 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2020-02-12 12:48:11.767  INFO 41316 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2020-02-12 12:48:11.768  INFO 41316 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.17]
2020-02-12 12:48:12.068  INFO 41316 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2020-02-12 12:48:12.069  INFO 41316 --- [           main] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 12810 ms
2020-02-12 12:48:12.526  INFO 41316 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2020-02-12 12:48:12.890 ERROR 41316 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase   : Failed to start component [Connector[HTTP/1.1-8080]]

org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Protocol handler start failed
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:1008) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.addConnector(StandardService.java:226) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.addPreviouslyRemovedConnectors(TomcatWebServer.java:259) ~[spring-boot-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.start(TomcatWebServer.java:197) ~[spring-boot-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.startWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:311) ~[spring-boot-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.finishRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:164) ~[spring-boot-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:552) ~[spring-context-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:142) ~[spring-boot-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775) ~[spring-boot-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316) ~[spring-boot-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260) ~[spring-boot-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248) ~[spring-boot-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at com.example.demo.DemoApplication.main(DemoApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:455) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:447) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:219) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:80) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.initServerSocket(NioEndpoint.java:236) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:210) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.bindWithCleanup(AbstractEndpoint.java:1103) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.start(AbstractEndpoint.java:1189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start(AbstractProtocol.java:568) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:1005) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    ... 14 common frames omitted

2020-02-12 12:48:12.896  INFO 41316 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2020-02-12 12:48:12.909  INFO 41316 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2020-02-12 12:48:12.912 ERROR 41316 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

The Tomcat connector configured to listen on port 8080 failed to start. The port may already be in use or the connector may be misconfigured.

Action:

Verify the connector's configuration, identify and stop any process that's listening on port 8080, or configure this application to listen on another port.

2020-02-12 12:48:12.915  INFO 41316 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Shutting down ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

This is a full stack trace - either provide yours or try to compare with mine...

Comment: I verified teh open ports and i this port is not in use. Ive tried several other ports whch are nt in use and still same issue.

Comment: maybe you don't see the open port because of lack or permissions?

Comment: Wouldn't we see BindException if this is caused by already used port?

Comment: @Seb - technically its Bind Exception, you're right, however in description there are lines presented in the original question. That's why I've assumed that the information in the question is not full. In any case I've updated the answer with the error of how does it should look like for the same case.

Comment: There is no bindexception in my log. All that is coming is ConnectorStartFailedException.                                 
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/web/embedded/tomcat/ConnectorStartFailedException.html

Comment: If so, maybe the connector uses SSL and it wasn't configured correctly... In any case I suggest you to download the sample project from start.spring.io and try to run it. If it works, the issue is in your application, if it doesn't - the issue is that the port is occupied by your operating system or there is some other issue

Answer (score 0):

1. Open cmd as administrator and enter the following commands:

`netstat -year | findstr 9330`

2. Once you find the process number, type it in the highlight of the following command:

`taskkill /F /PID <Process ID>`

3. The result should appear as follows:

SUCCESS: The process with PID < Process Id > has ended.